# HTML5 subtitles on Ted Talk Videos

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I noticed that on ted talks, when embedding the video flash there are subtitles if you choose to have them. However, the html5 version does not have any. I was wondering if there was any way to get this working. Right now I have the iframe opening up in a lightbox.

A hacky fix I can think of is have a floating div that changes the text based off the JSON subtitle file (ex: http://www.ted.com/talks/subtitles/id/70/lang/pt) but... if there's a better solution I'd love to know it. But if anyone knows how to implement the hacky fix, that'd be great also.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

[Here is an article](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/track/basics/) describing how to get started with the Track element, which you can use to add subtitles or captions.

**Edit:** build a separate file containing your HTML5 video and track markup, and then reference that as the iframe source.

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>


<iframe width="560" height="315" frameborder="0" src="YOUR_HTML5_VIDEO_PLUS_TRACK"></iframe>

</body>
</html>
```

Then, your .vtt file would look like:

```
railroad
00:00:10.000 --> 00:00:12.500
Left uninspired by the crust of railroad earth

manuscript
00:00:13.200 --> 00:00:16.900
that touched the lead to the pages of your manuscript.
```

You can make this .vtt file in any text editor, and change the file extension. You will need to host this on a web server, it will not work locally (e.g. src=file://)

Comment: I want to use their video player still (for legal reasons). Will this still work? They make us embed in an iframe i think

Comment: It should work, as you define what the video source is separate from implementing the Track element. You should even be able to use the same iframe, and set the javascript cues within it. I have not tested that but I assume that would work.

Comment: Do you think you can paste an example? I'm new to javascript and I'm not sure what you mean.

Comment: Posted the easiest example, one that doesn't require javascript. It does require you to manually create a .vtt file which will be read by the <track></track> tag element.

Comment: My edited code should work for you. Build a quick page using HTML5 and then set that as the source of your iframe. Your HTML5 markup should include the video plus track tags, you'll still need to create the subtitles via a .vtt file.